# jasmine: Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, asynchronous, jasmine

I have an angular service called `requestNotificationChannel`:

```
app.factory("requestNotificationChannel", function($rootScope) {

    var _DELETE_MESSAGE_ = "_DELETE_MESSAGE_";

    function deleteMessage(id, index) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast(_DELETE_MESSAGE_, { id: id, index: index });
    };

    return {
       deleteMessage: deleteMessage
    };

});
```

I am trying to unit test this service using jasmine:

```
"use strict";

describe("Request Notification Channel", function() {
    var requestNotificationChannel, rootScope, scope;

    beforeEach(function(_requestNotificationChannel_) {
        module("messageAppModule");

        inject(function($injector, _requestNotificationChannel_) {
            rootScope = $injector.get("$rootScope");
            scope = rootScope.$new();
            requestNotificationChannel = _requestNotificationChannel_;
        })

        spyOn(rootScope, '$broadcast');
    });


    it("should broadcast delete message notification", function(done) {

        requestNotificationChannel.deleteMessage(1, 4);
        expect(rootScope.$broadcast).toHaveBeenCalledWith("_DELETE_MESSAGE_", { id: 1, index: 4 });
        done();       
    });
});
```

I read about the Asynchronous Support in Jasmine, but as I am rather new to unit testing with javascript couldn't make it work.

I am receiving an error :

```
Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL
```

and my test is taking too long to execute (about 5s).

Can somebody help me providing working example of my code with some explanation?

Comment: Processing events is usually done in a digest cycle. Try adding scope.$apply() to your test instead of using Jasmine's async testing pattern

Comment: this does not worked. I added scope.$apply(); just after calling  requestNotificationChannel.deleteMessage(1, 4) but I receivethe same error...

Comment: I get the same error when [async tests take longer to run than `Jest` expects](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/docs/en/Troubleshooting.md#unresolved-promises) - very common while debugging and taking some time to inspect variables.

Comment: Try using lesser timeout instead. I got this error while using timeout = 5000. I replaced it with 2000 and it worked for me!

Comment: Leaving this here to help someone in my shoes. I had this error while running tests inside of a docker container. Tests would sometimes pass without any issues, but sometimes fail. I figured it was some kind of race condition but couldn't figure out why. I realised that I had an `afterEach` step that was clearing out the database (using the `deleteMany` method). Adding `jest.setTimeout(30000);` in the `beforeAll` method seems to have fixed this for me - I'm guessing since the database deletion is a network call (inside the condition), it was sometimes taking longer than 3 secs and throwing.

Answer (score 256):

Having an argument in your `it` function (`done` in the code below) will cause Jasmine to attempt an async call.

```
//this block signature will trigger async behavior.
it("should work", function(done){
  //...
});

//this block signature will run synchronously
it("should work", function(){
  //...
});
```

It doesn't make a difference what the `done` argument is named, its existence is all that matters. I ran into this issue from too much copy/pasta.

The Jasmine [Asynchronous Support](http://jasmine.github.io/2.4/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support) docs note that argument (named `done` above) is a callback that can be called to let Jasmine know when an asynchronous function is complete. If you never call it, Jasmine will never know your test is done and will eventually timeout.

Comment: The same is true for args in describe (in angular, you need to call inject in describe to do that)

Comment: @MartinBliss It is documented, I've justed suggested an edit to refer to the documentation: http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/2434606

Comment: Note to random Googlers coming across this question in the future: if you are using Protractor and run into this issue, this answer isn't what you're looking for - Protractor calls the callback by itself.

Comment: It fixed my problem and it was caused by the same cuplrit "copy/pasta"

Comment: `I ran into this issue from too much copy/pasta` Classic line and so true :D

Comment: @Vincent what's the Protractor users issue then if this error occurs?

Comment: @BrunoBieri Well, it's been 4.5 years since that comment, so I'm not really sure... I'd guess Angular.js's digest cycle not completing or something? I'm sorry, can't really help there today...

Comment: In edition to this: doing `() =>{...}` & `_ => {...}` are NOT the same thing. Jasmine will parse the `_` as an argument and lead you to this error.

Answer (score 82):

Even for async tests, there is a timeout that goes off in this cases, You can work around this error by increasing the value for the limit timeout to evaluate an async Jasmine callback

```
describe('Helper', function () {
    var originalTimeout;

    beforeEach(function() {
        originalTimeout = jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL;
        jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 1000000;
    });

    afterEach(function() {
      jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = originalTimeout;
    });

    it('Template advance', function(doneFn) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'public/your-end-point.mock.json',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data, response) {
                // Here your expected using data
                expect(1).toBe(1)
                doneFn();
            },
            error: function (data, response) {
                // Here your expected using data
                expect(1).toBe(1)
                doneFn();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Source: http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-42

Comment: This seems like not "the right way" to do it, but after adding a couple extra zeros for my Selenium test to run, this was a needed hack.

Comment: The original jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL is 60000 ms. So this example will actually make it six times shorter.

Comment: You're right I just put a random number in this example, thanks :)

Answer (score 20):

This error can also be caused by leaving out inject when initializing a service/factory or whatever. For example, it can be thrown by doing this:

```
var service;
beforeEach(function(_TestService_) {
    service = _TestService_;
});
```

To fix it just wrap the function with inject to properly retrieve the service:

```
var service;
beforeEach(inject(function(_TestService_) {
    service = _TestService_;
}));
```

Answer (score 20):

```
import { fakeAsync, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
```

use **fakeAsync**

```
beforeEach(fakeAsync (() => {

//your code

}));



describe('Intilalize', () => {
        it('should have a defined component', fakeAsync(() => {
            createComponent();
            expect(_AddComponent.ngOnInit).toBeDefined();
        }));
    });
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use [karma-jasmine](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-jasmine#readme) plugin to set the default time out interval globally.

Add this config in karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    client: {
      jasmine: {
        timeoutInterval: 10000
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This error started out of the blue for me, on a test that had always worked. I couldn't find any suggestions that helped until I noticed my Macbook was running sluggishly. I noticed the CPU was pegged by another process, which I killed. The Jasmine async error disappeared and my tests are fine once again.

Don't ask me why, I don't know. But in my circumstance it seemed to be a lack of system resources at fault.

Comment: Probably, when your CPU was free, the task finished before the default timeout. When the CPU was busy, the task you were testing took too long to complete.

Answer (score 5):

This is more of an observation than an answer, but it may help others who were as frustrated as I was.

I kept getting this error from two tests in my suite.  I thought I had simply broken the tests with the refactoring I was doing, so after backing out changes didn't work, I reverted to earlier code, twice (two revisions back) thinking it'd get rid of the error.  Doing so changed nothing.  I chased my tail all day yesterday, and part of this morning without resolving the issue.

I got frustrated and checked out the code onto a laptop this morning.  Ran the entire test suite (about 180 tests), no errors.  So the errors were never in the code or tests.  Went back to my dev box and rebooted it to clear anything in memory that might have been causing the issue.  No change, same errors on the same two tests.  So I deleted the directory from my machine, and checked it back out.  Voila! No errors.

No idea what caused it, or how to fix it, but deleting the working directory and checking it back out fixed whatever it was.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thank you man, i was going crazy about this. I rebooted my PC and that was it

Comment: In my case, I just re-ran the command and it resolved this issue. I had hot reload for the unit-tests and everytime it was failing. I had to stop and run command again.

Answer (score 3):

You also get this error when expecting something in the `beforeAll` function!

```
describe('...', function () {

    beforeAll(function () {
        ...

        expect(element(by.css('[id="title"]')).isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
    });

    it('should successfully ...', function () {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `done`, just leave the function call empty.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong but as I have understood it just makes the test suite finish before the very test and and the error message is dumped instead. Which means that any assert that fails won't break the test as the test suite is finished before the assert is run. It might also mean (I have seen similar behaviour) that another test shows the error this test created. Finally it means that everything looks ok to start with but as the number of tests grow the issue will pop up intermittently.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the test is waiting for some callback that never comes. It's likely because the test is not executed with asynchronous behavior.

First, see if just using fakeAsync in your "it" scenario:

```
it('should do something', fakeAsync(() => {
```

You can also use `flush()` to wait for the microTask queue to finish or `tick()` to wait a specified amount of time.

Answer (score 2):

Works after removing the `scope` reference and the function arguments:

```
"use strict";

describe("Request Notification Channel", function() {
    var requestNotificationChannel, rootScope;

    beforeEach(function() {
        module("messageAppModule");

        inject(function($injector, _requestNotificationChannel_) {
            rootScope = $injector.get("$rootScope");
            requestNotificationChannel = _requestNotificationChannel_;
        })
        spyOn(rootScope, "$broadcast");
    });


    it("should broadcast delete message notification with provided params", function() {
        requestNotificationChannel.deleteMessage(1, 4);
        expect(rootScope.$broadcast).toHaveBeenCalledWith("_DELETE_MESSAGE_", { id: 1, index: 4} );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, this error was caused by improper use of "fixture.detectChanges()" It seems this method is an event listener (async) which will only respond a callback when changes are detected. If no changes are detected it will not invoke the callback, resulting in a timeout error. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

What I did was: Added/Updated the following code:

```
framework: 'jasmine',
jasmineNodeOpts: 
{
    // Jasmine default timeout
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 60000,
    expectationResultHandler(passed, assertion) 
    {
      // do something
    },
}
```

Comment: Please explain why this code works, rather than just posting it without an explanation.

Comment: So basically when you execute a test and it takes longer than expected, it gets failed because the default time out was met and script didn't move forward in execution. This could happen due to some conditions not met (For example visibility, page loading). Now if your default time out is like 1000ms >> scripts would fail often because it's just one second and there could be multiple factors adding to the failure of your script. However, increasing your timeout interval can make browser/driver wait longer for conditions to met.

Comment: Okay, now word that into your post; you should try to avoid just answering with code without explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

> As noted by @mastablasta, but also to add that if you call the 'done' argument or rather name it **completed** you just call the callback completed() in your test when it's done.

```
// this block signature will trigger async behavior.
it("should work", function(done){
  // do stuff and then call done...
  done();
});

// this block signature will run synchronously
it("should work", function(){
  //...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 100000;

Keeping this in the block solved my issue.

```
it('', () => {
 jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 100000;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
beforeEach(() => {..
```

use

```
beforeEach(fakeAsync(() => {..
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, a timeout was cause because of a failed injection of a service with `providedIn: 'root'`. It's not clear why injection failed, nor why there was no early error if there is apparently no instance of provider available.

I was able to work around it by manually providing a value:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [
    // ...
  ],
  imports: [
    // ...
  ],
  providers: [
    // ...
    { provide: MyService, useValue: { /* ... */ } },
  ]
}).compileComponents();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have caught the same error because I used the `setTimeout` function in the component. Example:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.changeState();
  }
  
  private changeState(): void {
    setTimeout(() => this.state = StateEnum.IN_PROGRESS, 10000);
  }
```

When I changed the `timeout` from 10000ms to 0 or less than 5000ms (DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL), all tests were passed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was not returning the value from the spy method, hence facing error,

```
        mainMethod(args): Observable<something>{
            return nestedMethod().pipe();
        }
```

Your Test should like below,

```
        it('your test case', (done: DoneFn) => {
         const testData = {}; // Your data    
         spyOn(service, 'nestedMethod').and.returnValue(of(testData));
         const obxValue = service.mainMethod('your args');

         obxValue.pipe(first()).subscribe((data) => {
            expect(data).not.toBeUndefined();
            done();
         });
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

for someone facing this kind, I was writing a test for the first time and had this as test statement and test failing with timeout error.

```
  fit('log in with Facebook ', async done => {
```

Fix i found was adding `done()` as last statement of test.

```
fit('log in with Facebook ', async done => {
.....
.....

done();
})
```

Answer (score -2):

If you have an argument (`done`) in the `it` function try to remove it as well it's call within the function itself:

```
it("should broadcast delete message notification", function(/*done -> YOU SHOULD REMOVE IT */) {

    requestNotificationChannel.deleteMessage(1, 4);
    expect(rootScope.$broadcast).toHaveBeenCalledWith("_DELETE_MESSAGE_", { id: 1, index: 4 });
    // done(); -> YOU SHOULD REMOVE IT        
});
```

Comment: Without any explanation of why this answer isn't that useful.

Comment: this answer solved my problem... angular testing is a nightmare!