# Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified.... .DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, asynchronous, jasmine

I have an angular service class : -

```
angular.module('triggerTips')
       .service('userData', function ($rootScope, $http, $log, $firebase) {

    this._log = {
        service : 'userData'
    };

    // Synchronized objects storing the user data
    var config;
    var userState;

    // Loads the user data from firebase
    this.init = function(readyCallback) {
        var log = angular.extend({}, this._log);
        log.funct = 'init';

        var fireRef = new Firebase('https://XYZfirebaseio.com/' + $rootScope.clientName);
       config = $firebase(fireRef.child('config')).$asObject();
       userState = $firebase(fireRef.child('userState').child($rootScope.userName)).$asObject();

  Promise.all([config.$loaded(), userState.$loaded()]).
    then(
      function() {
        if(config == null || Object.keys(config).length < 4) {
          log.message = 'Invalid config';
          $log.error(log);
          return;
        }

        if(!userState.userProperties) {
          userState.userProperties = {};
        }

        if(!userState.contentProperties) {
          userState.contentProperties = {};
        } 

        log.message = 'User Properties: ' + JSON.stringify(userState.userProperties);
        $log.debug(log);

        log.message = 'Content Properties: ' + JSON.stringify(userState.contentProperties);
        $log.debug(log);

        log.message = 'Loaded user data from firebase';
        $log.debug(log);
        readyCallback();
      },
      function() {
        log.message = 'Unable to load user data from firebase';
        $log.error(log);
      }
    );
};

// Returns the initial tip configuration
this.getConfig = function() {
  return config;
};

// Set the value of a user property
// A user property is something about the user himself
this.setUserProperty = function(property, value) {
  if(!userState.userProperties) {
    userState.userProperties = {};
  }
  userState.userProperties[property] = value;
  userState.$save();
  $rootScope.$broadcast('user-property-change', property);
};

// Get the value of a user property
this.getUserProperty = function(property) {
  if(userState.userProperties) {
    return userState.userProperties[property];
  }
};

// Set the value of a user content property
// A content property is something about a particular peice of content for a particular user
this.setContentProperty = function(contentName, property, value) {
  if(!userState.contentProperties[contentName]) {
    userState.contentProperties[contentName] = {};
  }

  userState.contentProperties[contentName][property] = value;
  userState.$save();
  $rootScope.$broadcast('content-property-change', contentName, property);
};

// Increment a count property on the user state for a given tip
this.incrementContentProperty = function(contentName, property) {
  if(!userState.contentProperties[contentName]) {
    userState.contentProperties[contentName] = {};
  }
  if(!userState.contentProperties[contentName][property]) {
    userState.contentProperties[contentName][property] = 0;
  }

  userState.contentProperties[contentName][property]++;
  userState.$save();
  $rootScope.$broadcast('content-property-change', contentName, property);
};

// Returns the user state for a given tip and property
this.getContentProperty = function(contentName, property) {
  if(userState.contentProperties) {
    var t = userState.contentProperties[contentName];
    if(t) {
      return t[property];
    }
  }
};
});
```

I am trying to unit test this service using jasmine:-

my unit test is :-

```
    'use strict';

describe('Service: userData', function () {

  // load the service's module
  beforeEach(function() {
    module('triggerTips');
  });

  // instantiate service
  var userData;
  beforeEach(inject(function (_userData_) {
    userData = _userData_;
  }));

  it('should load correctly', function () {
    expect(!!userData).toBe(true);
  });

  describe('after being initialized', function () {

    beforeEach(function(done) {
      // Unable to get this working because the callback is never called
        userData.init(function() {
            done();
        });
        jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 2000;
    });

    it('should have a valid config', function (done) {
         setTimeout(function() {
             expect(Object.keys(userData.getConfig()).length == 0);
             done();
           }, 1500);}); }); });
```

I read about the Asynchronous Support in Jasmine, but as I am rather new to unit testing with JavaScript couldn't make it work.

I am receiving an error :

> Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by
>   jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL

Can somebody help me providing working example of my code with some explanation?

Comment: readyCallback is called when promises are resolved. You need to resolve the promises and trigger a digest, see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#differences-between-kris-kowal-s-q-and-q

Comment: Thanks for your reply how can i correct without to make changes in service, please help me to out from this

Comment: You don't need to change the source code. You should be using mocks for config and userState and return resolved promises on their $loaded functions, then call $scope.$apply in your test. If you set up a fiddle with your code I can show it there.

Comment: littel get your point can you please do one test case for me ? it will very helpfull for me

Comment: Try to remove 'done' Parameter. Answer inspired from [this question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604644/jasmine-async-callback-was-not-invoked-within-timeout-specified-by-jasmine-defa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest that you replace `setTimeout` with `$timeout` so as to speed up your spec suite. You will need [ngMock](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock) to be a part of your spec suite in order to get this working the intended way, but that seems to have already been taken care of looking at your spec. Good stuff.

Then in order to make the async nature of the spec *"go away"* you would call:

[$timeout.flush([delay])](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$timeout) where  `delay` is optional.

- If no delay is passed, all the pending async tasks (*inside the angular world*) will finish what they're doing.
- If a delay is passed, all pending tasks within the specified delay will finish. Those outside of the specified delay will remain in a 'pending' state.

With this, you can remove the `done` callback and write your tests as such:

```
describe('after being initialized', function () {
  var $timeout;

  beforeEach(function () {
    // Unable to get this working because the callback is never called
    userData.init();

    inject(function ($injector) {
      $timeout = $injector.get('$timeout');
    });
  }));

  it('should have a valid config', function () {
    $timeout.flush();
    // callback should've been called now that we flushed().
    expect(Object.keys(userData.getConfig()).length).toEqual(0);
  });
});
```

What `Promise` implementation are you using? I see a call to `Promise.all` but for the sake of continuing on with my answer I'm going to **assume** it is equivalent to `$q.all`. Running `$timeout.flush` should take care of resolving those values.

If you want to write expectations on the rejected/resolved values of a promise in Jasmine, I would look into something like [jasmine-promise-matchers](https://github.com/bvaughn/jasmine-promise-matchers) to make it clean and pretty, but barring that you could do something like this:

```
// $q
function get () {
  var p1 = $timeout(function () { return 'x'; }, 250);
  var p2 = $timeout(function () { return 'y'; }, 2500); 

  return $q.all([p1, p2]);
}

// expectation
it('is correct', function () {
  var res; 

  get().then(function (r) {
    res = r;
  });

  $timeout.flush(2500);

  expect(res).toEqual(['x', 'y']);
});
```

Depending on your setup, you may or may not have to stub out/spy on (depending on your frameworks definition of a *spy*) the promise in relation to your local `config` variable, but that's another story altogether I reckon.

*I am not at all familiar with $firebase(something).$asObject.$loaded - as such I may have missed something here, but assuming it works 'just like any other promise' you should be good to go.*

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cmn4hjw0/2/)**