# Timeouts occur on different platforms when running e2e test using protractor

Tags: macos, jasmine, protractor, jasmine2.0

I am using protractor to perform e2e tests but i keep getting this error message:

```
- Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

I have increased the timeout limit to 60 seconds and i still get this error. The big problem about this is that the error occurs when running the tests on mac OS. When running the tests in a Virtual Machine using ubuntu all tests pass.

Both the VM and Mac OS machine has the same version of everything that is needed and both of the machines are running the tests in chrome. Is there some special guidelines i should keep in mind when writing protractor tests that is meant to be executed on different operating systems?

Answer (score 0):

You certainly *can* see different behavior on different OSs... the `CONTROL` vs `COMMAND` keys comes to mind. That said, I would think you've got a bug somewhere in your code. Perhaps isolating tests until you find the culprit?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as @Brine says there would be some browser.actions in your code which uses the keys different from other OS.

And also for me allScriptsTimeout made an issue so i have corrected that too.

May be the below urls i have refereed while i got the issue they might help.

[jasmine 2 - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29218981/jasmine-2-async-callback-was-not-invoked-within-timeout-specified-by-jasmine-d)

[Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified.... .DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29226940/error-timeout-async-callback-was-not-invoked-within-timeout-specified-de)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, on Ubuntu all tests passes, but on Mac OS - no.
I manage to fix it by setting `browser.ignoresynchronization = false` before the tests.
Unfortunately this causes other problems on Ubuntu.