# How to take page screenshot in a hybrid mobile application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, oracle-jet

I would like to take a screenshot of the current page on a button click from a hybrid app and need to send it in mail using javascript or jquery.

I have tried with html2canvas.js , but it doesn't work properly.

can anyone give me a solution for this.

Thanks

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527), if you have a problem, please post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read the ['How to Ask a good question' guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527)

Comment: I second @RoryMcCrossan comment but also reference this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-in-browser-screenshots/6678156#6678156

Comment: Without knowing your problem as other comments said, you must consider that you won't get any image from any html from other server where the web app is located. For that you will need to make it througth the server, so the only solution for you is sure to make something in native code if that is your case

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41831908/error-unable-to-capture-screenshot-android-hybrid-app-using-protractor-and-ap