# Async callback was not invoked - when run test in IE browser

Tags: protractor

When I run test in IE browser I get following error: 
`Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.`

I have tried increasing the `allScriptsTimeout : 120000` and `defaultTimeoutInterval : 120000` but it does not help.

here is my config file:

```
allScriptsTimeout : 120000,
capabilities : {
        'browserName' : 'internet explorer',
    },
    localSeleniumStandaloneOpts : {
          'jvmArgs' : ['-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/IEDriverServer3.3.0.exe']    
        },
jasmineNodeOpts : {
        defaultTimeoutInterval : 120000
    },
```

Comment: Maybe try specifying the version of internet explorer?  See the config posted here https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/669

Comment: Hi @sonia sharma,   would it be possible to provide the snippet of your test case? i hope there would be some other reasons too for failure

Comment: I hope this would help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604644/jasmine-async-callback-was-not-invoked-within-timeout-specified-by-jasmine-defa

Comment: Is it an angular app? Does it happens only on IE?

Comment: yes, it happens only in IE on chrome and Firefox test runs is fine.

Comment: `it('Logout ', function() {
     LogoutPage.adminIcon.click()
          browser.waitForAngular();
          LogoutPage.logoutBtn.click();
          expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toMatch('#/LogIn');
    });` If I remove the expect, test does not timeout. this issue is only with IE for other browser I do not see timeout issue.

Comment: Any suggestion on how this issue can be fixed ?