# unit test ES6 promises (.then, .catch)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I'm using AngularJS and ES6, So I want to write a unit test for the ES6 (not using angular.mock ...) this is how I tried to test it. but the problem is  `it('resolves its promise with the current data'` it fails with the

```
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

I removed the `done()` based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25273095/5134285) but the test always passes, doesn't matter `toEqual` what!. maybe the response variable doesn't set correctly.

Does someone have any idea!?

**data.service.js**

```
    export class DataService {
     'ngInject';
      constructor($log, $http) {
        this.$log = $log;
        this.$http = $http;
      }
      getData(url, name) {
        return this.$http.get(url)
          .then((response) => {
            return {data: response.data, version: response.version)};
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            this.$log.error('Failed for getData.\n' + angular.toJson(error.data, true));
            throw error.data || {};
          });
       }
    }
```

**data.service-spec.js**

```
import {DataService} from './data.service';

let sysUnderTest, mapSelectionServiceMock, http;

describe('http.get', () => {
  let temperaturePromise;
  let promiseHelper;
  let getDataPromise;

  beforeEach(() => {
    let fetchPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      promiseHelper = {
        resolve: resolve,
        reject: reject
      };
    });

    // http mock
    http = {
      get: () => {}
    };
    spyOn(http, 'get').and.returnValue(fetchPromise);
    sysUnderTest = new DataService(null, http, null, null, null);
    getDataPromise = sysUnderTest.getData('sampleURL');
  });

  it('getData', () => {
    expect(http.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(getDataPromise).toEqual(jasmine.any(Promise));
  });

  describe('on successful get', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
      let response = new Response(JSON.stringify({
        data: 78,
        version: 1
      }));
      promiseHelper.resolve(response);
    });

    it('resolves its promise with the current data', function(done) {
        getDataPromise.then(function(data) {
          expect(data).toEqual(79987);
          done();
        });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: The idea is that you shouldn't mix Angular $q promises with ES6 promises, unless you know what you're doing very well. You can't rely on [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25273095/5134285) you've cited because of that. $q promise is synchronous. ES6 promise is not. This test tests something that never happens in real service. I've checked the code and still not sure what could go wrong here - but it could. You don't `catch` in a test, while you should. What's `Response`? If it's https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response, it won't work as you expect.

Comment: @estus, thanks, yeah it is kind of complicated, the question is I am not sure if it is a correct unit test. In this case what could be the correct and probably good way to test the `getData` method from the `DataService` class. How should I test the `.then` and `.catch`. `response`can be a json object. as you see `data=80` and `version=1` as an example

Comment: I'd suggest to not reinvent the wheel and stick to ngMock and $q promises for unit tests, they are very straightforward and efficient. You should add `catch` to `getDataPromise.then` because if the test fails, it should call `done.fail` and not result in test timeout, like it possibly is in your case. Again, the origin of `Response` is unknown, and it may cause an error.

Comment: the problem is the project is already there, and not allow for refactoring and using $q. therefore I must use the es6 promises in unit test. but without changing the code and using the ngMock and $q => this is my next question for how to do it?

Comment: The code you've posted (data.service.js and $http) uses $q promises, so the problem appears. Obviously, it's preferable to stick to $q in tests to test $q promises, and Promise for testing native promises, because those two aren't interchangeable. Even though the test may pass at some point, it doesn't test real code - it may stay green at some point while the app stops working as expected.

Comment: OK, now I got where is(could be) the problem, thanks. Is it possible for you to provide a sample test for the `data.service.js` with $q. I never use it before in test.

Comment: I'm out of time and can't offer workable example for now, and this one is supposed to be quite extensive here. I'd suggest to check https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing first. I would suggest to test DataService service instead of DataService class because it will test DI as well. And $http requests are supposed to be mocked with https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend in ngMock. Check also also https://github.com/bvaughn/jasmine-promise-matchers for $q promise assertions.