# $q in Angular or Promises in ES6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, angular-promise, es6-promise

I have a project using ES6 and AngularJS, and as far as I found, AngularJS $q promises is synchronous but ES6 promises not. Right?
The question is, what are the differences? and when should I use $q or ES6?
I know what is the difference between Synchronous and Asynchronous, but got confused between `new Promise` and `AngularJS $q`.

raise from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46917005/unit-test-es6-promises-then-catch?noredirect=1#comment80784131_46917005)

Comment: What do you mean by "$q promises is synchronous"? I don't know Angular and i don't want to, but even looking at their docs didn't help me much. Isn't the whole point of promises to help us write asynchronous code (and avoid callback hell)?

Comment: `Right?` - wrong. Promises are by definition asynchronous. The difference between $q and ES6 Promises is that $q Promises (at least a few months back, could be fixed now) are not quite Promise/A+ spec compliant

Comment: `$q Promises (at least a few months back) are not quite Promise/A+ spec compliant` what does it mean?

Comment: @JaromandaX $q promises  wrap new Promise

Comment: @charlietfl - that may well be the case now, but it wasn't a few months back

Comment: @Milban - it means that $q **was** a Promise implementation that wasn't quite compliant with [this specification](https://promisesaplus.com/)

Comment: @charlietfl Yes. And `new Promise` is... [$q promise](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.6.6/src/ng/q.js#L315-L317).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement about `$q` synchronicity applies to unit tests with `ngMock`  in the first place.

`$q` promises are *capable* of being synchronous in production:

```
let foo;

$q.resolve().then(() => { foo = 1 });
$rootScope.$digest();
console.log(foo === 1);
```

And they are *supposed* to be synchronous in unit tests, because all AngularJS services that are responsible for asynchronous behaviour (`$timeout`, `$http`, etc) are mocked with ngMock in order to make tests fully synchronous:

```
it('...', inject(($q) => {
    let foo;

    $q.resolve().then(() => { foo = 1 });
    $rootScope.$digest();
    expect(foo).toBe(1);
}));
```

While ES6 promises are asynchronous by design, and `then` callback runs on next tick:

```
it('...', (done) => {
    let foo;

    Promise.resolve(1).then(() => {
      foo = 1;
      expect(foo).toBe(1);
    })
    .then(done, done.fail);
});
```