# How to scroll a div and click on buttons with specific button text

Tags: typescript, selenium, automation, protractor, e2e-testing

I am trying to automate instagram following. I go to a profile and click on the followers link. It opens a modal type div and there are all the followers. I want to click on all the follow buttons except the unfollow and requested buttons. But the problem is there is a scroll bar and while finding the element using automation, it is not able to find all the buttons.

[image]

Below sharing the method I wrote to collect all follow buttons and click and when the buttons that are present in the dom are over it scrolls down by pressing page down button.

testHelper.retry is just a function which retries 10 times to find an element for a given time period before it performs any action like clicking or sendKeys

```
element(by.xpath("//div[@role='dialog']")).element(by.tagName("ul")).all(by.buttonText("Follow")).then(links => {
            console.log("Links Length" + links.length);
            if (links.length == 0) {
                this.ScrollDown();
            }
            else {
                for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
                    browser.sleep(3000);
                    testHelper.retry(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(links[i]),
                        10,
                        90000,
                        true);
                    links[i].click().then(() => {
                        console.log("Number of follow buttons: " + links.length);
                        this.numberOfProfilesFollowed = i + 1;
                        browser.sleep(3000);
                        console.log("i: " + (i + 1));
                        if (i >= links.length - 2) {
                            this.ScrollDown();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is the issue here and do yo have any error message? Is there any standard element present in the dialog other than the name and follow/un-follow button at the end of dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of clicking the desired elements try using `Actions`, something like this should help you:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(webDriver);
actions.moveToElement(element).click().perform();
```

In your case `element` will be each of the elements that has the 'Follow' text present.

Comment: All the follow buttons are not present in the dom. Once we scroll down they become visible some at a time. Will it work in that case too?

Comment: There is no function as "moveToElement" for actions. I am working in typescript

Comment: I think it is mouseMove(element) if it is protractor.

Comment: Ok it is working. But after clicking all the follow buttons that are present in the DOM it scrolls down. After 1-2 scrolls it shows error:

Comment: Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.

Comment: browser.wait(browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.PAGE_DOWN).perform().then(function () {
            console.log("Scrolled down");
        }), 90000);
        browser.sleep(5000);

Comment: this is my scroll function

Comment: Seems like a different problem, upon quick google I found this topic, it may lead you further:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604644/jasmine-async-callback-was-not-invoked-within-timeout-specified-by-jasmine-defa

Comment: Ok I will check it out. Thank you for your help. It really optimized my code.